# Where can I eat a cobra (or any snake) in Hong Kong?

Tags: food-and-drink, hong-kong

I was reading [a travel article by Nick Tosches in *Vanity Fair* on his search for opium dens](http://www.vanityfair.com/culture/features/2000/09/opium-dens-200009) in Asia. One section stood out for me:

> Cobra soup—the more venomous the serpent, the more potent the tonic;
>   gelatinous and steaming and delicious beyond description—garnished
>   with petals of snow-white chrysanthemum. Later, amid the crowded
>   stalls of the night market, we watch as an elderly Chinese man hands
>   over a small fortune in cash to another elderly man, a snake seller
>   much esteemed for the rarity and richness of poison of his stock. The
>   snake man pockets the money, narrows his eyes, and with a studied
>   suddenness withdraws a long, writhing serpent from a cage of bamboo.
>   Holding it high, his grasp directly below its inflated venom glands,
>   its mouth open, its fangs extended, he slashes it with a razor-sharp
>   knife from gullet to midsection, the movement of the blade in his hand
>   following with precise rapidity the velocity of the creature’s
>   powerful whiplashings, which send its gushing blood splattering
>   wildly. Laying down the blade, the snake man reaches his
>   blood-drenched hand with medical exactitude into the open serpent,
>   withdraws its still-living bladder, drops it into the eager hands of
>   his customer, who, with gore dripping from between his fingers onto
>   his shirt, raises the pulsing bloody organ to his open mouth, gulps it
>   down, and wipes and licks away the blood that runs down his chin.

I have tried time and again in my travels around Asia to find any place that sells snake, without any luck. So I'm looking for advice here:

- Firstly, is it legal to eat a cobra or any other species of snake in Hong Kong?
- If yes, then where can I find it? Is there any particular locality or restaurant that specialises in it?
- The article mentions "a small fortune in cash" being required for payment. How 'expensive', in real terms, would this gastronomic experience be?

Comment: You haven't seen snake for sale in Asia?  More than once in Shanghai I've seen street vendors with live snakes for sale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [an article on SFGate that gives details of a locality in Kowloon](http://www.sfgate.com/cgi-bin/article.cgi?file=/c/a/2006/01/15/TRGOHGLO2K1.DTL) (emphasis mine):

> And that's where **Kweilin**, in Kowloon's teeming **Sham Shui Po**, comes in.
>   Known far and wide as **Snake Street**, it's the place to find the
>   freshest snake in town. How fresh? Fresh enough to try to get in the
>   first bite. Part of the fun of a **Kweilin Street** visit is watching a
>   waiter trying to wrestle a 5-foot python toward a chopping block.

---

**UPDATE:** I didn't have time to look up Snake Street in Sham Shui Po. Instead, I found a restaurant called **Ser Wong Fun** (30 Cochrane Street) in Central. If you keep following the path of shops to the left of the Central-Mid Levels Escalator, you'll come across this place as Cochrane Street is parallel to it; Ser Wong Fun is near the base of the one of the escalator legs. It is (supposedly) mentioned in the Michelin Guide (or something related to Michelin, there was a newspaper clipping in the restaurant), and it's not that expensive.

[image: Ser Wong Fun snake soup]

Photo credit: [Ankur Banerjee](http://www.ankurb.info)

A 'five-snake' soup cost 100 HKD; I asked the owner what kind of snakes were in it, but she didn't speak much English, from what I can gather, it was an assortment of garden snakes. So my quest to eat a cobra is still alive!

My [friend](https://twitter.com/#!/shreya05) came up with a list of other restaurants in Hong Kong which also serve snake; again, we didn't have time to explore those options. I include these two for the sake of completeness in case the research helps someone.

- **Shai Wong Hup**, 170 Ap Liu Street, Sham Shui Po
- **See Wong Yan**, 80 Woosung Streen, Jordan

Answer (score 5):

From the [Wikitravel piece on Hong Kong and eating exotic meats](http://wikitravel.org/en/Hong_Kong#Exotic_meats), it sounds like there are a few restaurants that sell it and it's likely legal.  They even name restaurants that sell it:

> While Hong Kong has long banned dog and cat meat and has strict rules
>   on importing many meats of wild life animals, snake meat is commonly
>   seen in winter in different restaurants that bear the name "Snake
>   King". Served in a sticky soup, it is believed to warm your body.

[About.com states](http://gohongkong.about.com/od/wheretostayinhk/tp/hong_kong_food_guide.htm) that Kowloon is probably the place to go:

> A favourite winter warmer in Hong Kong, snake soup is considered
>   somewhat of a gourmet dish. Most of the city’s snake meat is now
>   delivered chilled or frozen from China, but to try the meat and the
>   soup at its best you need to have it fresh, which means braving the
>   handful of **live snake restaurants that still exist in Kowloon**. Here,
>   you pluck your favourite python or cobra from behind a cage and watch
>   him slither to the chopping block, with more unusual snakes attracting
>   heavier price tags. The soup comes with the snake shredded inside,
>   although, if you’re braver, you can try sliced snake in a host of
>   other dishes. As it seems with almost all exotic meats, many say it
>   tastes like chicken.

But probably the most useful article (for you) comes from the [Wall Street Journal](http://blogs.wsj.com/scene/2010/10/08/dish-braised-five-snake-soup/) which lists contact details AND a price:

> Price: 800 HKD [~100 USD] (serves four). Cuisine Cuisine, IFC Mall, Central, Hong
>   Kong, tel: +852 2393 3933

The article was written in 2010, so there's still a reasonable chance it'll be around.

Comment: I still haven't been able to find out WHERE in Kowloon I can find these snake meet shops!

Answer (score 4):

Try **[Se Wong Yee](http://travel.nytimes.com/travel/guides/asia/china/hong-kong/74552/se-wong-yee/restaurant-detail.html)**, 24 Percival St, Causeway Bay, Hong Kong call (852/2831 0163).

This restaurant is famous for snake soup.